# PostgreSQL Command fom bash script

Tags: bash, postgresql

I work with PostgreSQL 9.2 and bash script. I have a  problem.

My DB is **TestDB** ,
Table name is **config**

and my bash code is

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "select count(*) from public.config where var_name='url'"
```

result is

ERROR:  relation "public.config" does not exist

Can anybody help me?

Comment: sudo -u postgres psql TestDB -c "select count(*) from config where var_name='url'"

Comment: @Patrick You should make that an answer, so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ok i did ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo -u postgres psql TestDB -c "select count(*) from config where var_name='url'
```

The Database was missing, so you executed the command into postgres db where you probably don't have that table ;-)